# Xamarin listview duplicate number count

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, count

I'm building an xamarin app I have a listview that holds numbers, what I am looking for is a way to count the number of times a number has been duplicated. Rather it is in an alert or message box or a count on the side of the listview.

Any ideas or code would be great

Comment: Use Linq and GroupBy on the list to get the count

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.